# Remove a specific item from a longlistselector in wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have a items in longlistselector. So i was trying to delete a specific item from a longlistselector in wp7 c#?

Comment: share that items you have created for. without giving the source, we can't answer for your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to declare your itemsource for your longlistselector to be type ObservableCollection , so that when you modify your itemsource, your longlistselector would response to the change accordingly.

T could be your custom type, for example :

```
//Photo is my custom class
ObservableCollection<Photo> photos;
```

Example code :

```
//Declare itemsource    
ObservableCollection<string> list;

//Bind to longlistselector dynamically somewhere in code
longlistselector.ItemSource = list;

//Add items into your source
list.Add("test1");
list.Add("test2");
list.Add("test3");

//Delete items
list.RemoveAt(input item index here);

//OR

list.Remove(item); //if you're able to retrieve item ref;
```

And in your xaml :

```
//Notice the {Binding } syntax below for ItemSource property
<phone:LongListSelector ItemsSource="{Binding }" SelectionChanged="longListSelector_SelectionChanged"  Name="longListSelector" />
```

Hope it works well for you.

A code example for reference :

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/LongListSelector-Demo-45364cc9

Answer (score 0):

You can use the simple method removeAt(position)

Comment: or remove(object) if implements the serializable